# .htaccess condition will omit ranges of ip addresses, but that i can modify as i see valid addresses in logs

Tags: regex, mod-rewrite, iis-6, regex-negation

I have the following in my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} (\b88\.78\.30\.\d{1,3}|\b182\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}|etc..)
RewriteRule (.*) http://www\.foobar\.com/botcatch.html [I,RP]
```

As i look at my logs, i want to exclude valid ip addresses in the class D range.  So I want to add for example 88.78.30.20 to NOT be included in this list.  I have looked at negative lookaheads in many posts on this board.  But I still don't get them.

Comment: Does IIS6 use .htaccess? Or did you mean a different tag.

Comment: RewriteCond and RewriteRule are the correct tags. IIS7 has the rewrite mod built in. For IIS6, Helitech wrote an extension. This is a basic regex question. I can't figure out how to use look aheads within the above RewriteCondition.  They use the Perl regex flavor.

Comment: I ask because the exact flavor of regex depends on what you are working with, mod-rewrite is usually related to Apache so I was unsure if the particular flavor you were describing would be different or not.

Comment: THanks Guvante.  I retagged this to include mod-rewrite; to pull in other experts with Apache based server knowledge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Negative lookaheads are zero length matches when they fail to see something, here is a supplement to what you mentioned:

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} (\b88\.78\.30\.(?!20)\d{1,3}|\b182\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}|etc..)
```

Note that this is chainable so you can do the following too:

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} (\b88\.78\.30\.(?!20|40)\d{1,3}|\b182\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}|etc..)
```

So if a word boundary is followed by `88.78.30.` and then not `20` or `40` but 1 to 3 digits.

Comment: Works great, thanks Guvante!  How do I mark your answer as the correct one?

Comment: @user2367669: There should be an empty checkmark next to the 0, note that you can also upvote it to show it was helpful.